# How to set onClick event of button to multiple functions (depending on prop) in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a custom button which renders a button like this:

```
<button>{this.props.text}</button>
```

This button is called ButtonCustom, what I want to do in the render method of the main container is this:

```
function myFunc1{
    doSomething();
}
function myFunc2{
    doSomething();
}

<ButtonCustom text="sometext" onClick={myFunc1}></ButtonCustom>
<ButtonCustom text="sometext" onClick={myFunc2}></ButtonCustom>
```

This however isn't working as the button doesn't execute the functions, how could I make it work?

Comment: I think you are missing binding this, <ButtonCustom text="sometext" onClick={this.myFunc1.bind(this)}></ButtonCustom>, do the same for other button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to also pass as props the **onCLick** function to your custom button:

```
export const ButtonCustom = ({ onClick, text }) => (
    <button type="button" onClick={onClick}>
        {text}
    </button>
);
```

Now you'll be able to fire the onClick event in your button:

```
<ButtonCustom text="sometext" onClick={myFunc1}></ButtonCustom>
```

> Bear in mind that if you have a custom component in react, nothing
>   will be automatically injected in the render code unless you
>   explicitly pass it as props

Comment: How will myFunc1 will get execute without binding this?

Comment: If you use an arrow function, you don't need to bind it. Just do `const myFunc1 = _ => { doSomething(); }`